# Как добавить HTML / CSS код в вопрос и сделать его исполняемым?

Tags: поддержка, сниппеты, редактор

Не пойму, как некоторые добавляют код и его можно выполнять прям тут же?

Comment: В инструментах обработки ответа выберите "фрагмент кода"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Называется сниппетом, делается вот этой кнопкой. Но это только для html/css/js/jsx.

> [image: скриншот]